# Japserserver HTTP 404 error

Tags: http, tomcat, logging, http-status-code-404, jasperserver

Could someone please help me to figure out this issue.I have installed the japserserver trial version for windows xp.The tomcat server seems to work fine.But when I try to connect to the japserserver i get a `HTTP 404` error.

```
SEVERE: A web application appears to have started a TimerThread named 
[adhocCache] via the java.util.Timer API but has failed to stop it.
To prevent a memory leak, the timer (and hence the enter code here associated thread) 
has been forcibly cancelled.
Jul 15, 2013 4:22:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Server startup in 30926 ms
```

In the localhost file under tomcat logs i could also see some error as:

```
Caused by: net.sf.ehcache.config.InvalidConfigurationException: There is one error in your configuration:
    * CacheManager configuration: You've assigned more memory to the on-heap than the VM can sustain, please adjust your -Xmx setting accordingly
```

`